# Rounding within avg() over () clause not working - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Does anybody know how to rewrite this 7-day moving average query in SQL Server, so that I get the value rounded 2 decimal places after the comma?

Current query:

```
SELECT round(avg(amount) OVER (
            ORDER BY DATE ASC rows BETWEEN 6 preceding
                    AND CURRENT row
            ), 2) average_amount
```

Current output:

```
120.00
121.00
120.00
```

Desired output:

```
120.11
121.18
120.20
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you give me your `amount` type? Anyway, the sample data with the corresponding result would be help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run it like this:

```
Select round(avg(amount*1.0) over (order by date asc ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND current row),2) average_amount
```

Sometimes it just needs *1.0